# how can i print the all objects in the tree set not just the last one?

Tags: java

i made a class called "ACCOUNT_OPTION" this class have a lot of arrays for customer ( name ,national ID .... etc ) and a lot a of method ( withdraw , deposit ,loan .... etc )
in the mean class called "bank"
i create a new object like in the pic :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int Selected  ;
    boolean again ;

    ACCOUNT_OPTIONS CUSTOMER = new ACCOUNT_OPTIONS ();

    do{ 
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            do {
                again = true;
                System.out.println("=================================");
                System.out.println("====== Welcome To Our Bank =======");
                System.out.println("Choose Your Choices ...");
                System.out.println("1) Create A New Account ...");
                System.out.println("2) Check Balance Amuont ...");
                System.out.println("3) Deposit...");
                System.out.println("4) Withdraw...");
                System.out.println("5) Get a new loan ...");
                System.out.println("6) Pay for the monthly payment for an existing loan...");
                System.out.println("7) Check an existing loan status ...");
                System.out.println("8) Print A Summry For Your Account...");
                System.out.println("9) Exit");
                System.out.print("Enter your choice :  ");
                Selected = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("=================================");

            switch(Selected) {
                case 1 : 
                    CUSTOMER.newaccount();
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    CUSTOMER.opaccountCheck();
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    CUSTOMER.opaccountDeposit();
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    CUSTOMER.opaccountWithdraw();
                    break;
                case 5 :
                    CUSTOMER.Loan();
                    break;
                case 6 :
                    CUSTOMER.LoanPay();
                    break;
                case 7 :
                    CUSTOMER.LoanCheck();
                    break;
                case 8 :
                    System.out.println(CUSTOMER);
                    break;
                case 9 : 
                    System.out.println(".....THANKS FOR VISITING.....");
                    System.out.println("---------------------");
                    break;
                default :
                    System.out.println(".....Invalid Choice.....");
                    System.out.println("---------------------");
                }
            }while(Selected!=9);
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(".....Error!!.....");
            System.out.println("Please Try Again");
            System.out.println("Please Enter Only Number");
            System.out.println("If You Want To Exit Press (9)");
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            again = false;
            }
    }while(!again);



    // here we store the accounts in TreeSet

    TreeSet<ACCOUNT_OPTIONS> Set = new TreeSet<>();
    Set.add(CUSTOMER);

    Iterator <ACCOUNT_OPTIONS> T = Set.iterator();
    System.out.println("\n"+"Tree set data: ");
    while (T.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(T.next());
   }
    }
}
```

every thing is ok the problem that when i want to print the Treeset it's just print the last account created but, i want it to print the all accounts what can i do :(

Comment: To start, follow Java coding standards for capitalization; your code is difficult to read because it's all confused. And you aren't showing the rest of your code, but it looks like you're only creating the set at the end of your program and adding the last customer before printing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're only adding one object to the `TreeSet`.

As it stands, you're instantiating your `CUSTOMER` object before the loop, then overriding it with each iteration of the loop, without ever adding it to your collection. Notice that, when you instantiate your `TreeSet` after the loop, you're then only calling `add( )` *once*, so you're only adding *one* object, which is the `CUSTOMER` object created by the last iteration of the loop.

Try this:

```
//BEFORE the loop
AccountOptions customer; 
TreeSet<AccountOptions> accountOptionsSet= new TreeSet<>();
do { 
    //INSIDE the loop 
    customer = new Account_Options() 
    ... rest of loop / instance-creation logic  
    accountOptionsSet.add(customer); //store the object before it gets overridden by the next. 
    ... 
 } while(!again);

 //AFTER the loop 
System.out.println("\n"+"Tree set data: ");

Iterator <AccountOptions> accountOptionsIterator = accountOptionsSet.iterator();
while (accountOptionsIterator.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(accountOptionsIterator.next());
}
```

(Note that I made some changes to your syntax to conform to [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) and [meaningful-names](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/variable.html) best practices. While not necessary to make your code work, you should really learn about and follow those. That said, the ones I suggested may or may not be appropriate for your particular use case - I'm going on what I can deduce from what you've posted. In fact, some of the changes I made are still bad - for instance, `acctOptionsSet` should have a name that's more meaningful in your context.)

Also, without knowing anything else about what you're doing, `AccountOptions customer` is confusing. Ask yourself: Why not have a `Customer` class that has field called `options` of the `AccountOptions` class, or even a `Customer` class with an `Account` field, which has an `Options` field?

As you're learning to program, you might be tempted to think that making something hard to understand makes it smart - *it doesn't*. [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) is arguably nowhere more applicable than in programming.

Comment: where i must place "acctOptionsSet.add(customer);" in ma code cuz I've tried to place it just like u said but it didn't work the out put still the last account

Comment: @Esraa It needs to be placed exactly where I've placed it, but that's not the only change I made. The `TreeSet` you print from must be instantiated *before* the loop, added to *inside* the loop, and printed - only *printed* - after the loop.

Comment: in print i write it like u they said it's wrong . i think treeset need Iterator right ? if it's not ,i even cant replace (T.hasNext()) to (acctOptionsSet.hasNext()) and what i do with "T" in System.out.println(T.next()); if i delete the Iterator ? i'm sorry if i'm asking a lot of thing but i just want it to work and i want to know how

Comment: @Esraa correct, it does need an iterator. That was a typo I made between edits. See updated answer.

Comment: the class Account_Options code is soo long i cant post it here